# Is there a tool to discover if the same class exists in multiple jars in the classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

If you have two jars in your classpath that contain different versions of the same class, the classpath order becomes critical.

I am looking for a tool that can detect and flag such potential conflicts in a given classpath or set of folders.

Certainly a script that starts:

```
classes=`mktemp`
for i in `find . -name "*.jar"`
do
    echo "File: $i" > $classes
    jar tf $i > $classes
    ...
done
```

with some clever sort/uniq/diff/grep/awk later on has potential, but I was wondering if anyone knows of any existing solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect duplicate JARs in the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878003/how-to-detect-duplicate-jars-in-the-classpath)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) tool from JBoss is another candidate: "Spot if a class/package is located in multiple JAR files"

Comment: Try jarfish as well (my other answer); I used it successfully

Comment: Yup! Either this or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135971/is-there-a-tool-to-discover-if-the-same-class-exists-in-multiple-jars-in-the-clas/4516827#4516827 should do the trick!

Comment: Is there a tool/way that filters only used (imported) classes?
We have a lot of duplicate classes in our classpath that are actually never used

Answer (score 9):

Looks like [jarfish](http://code.google.com/p/jarfish/wiki/Intro) will do what you want with its "dupes" command.

Comment: Nice! Either this or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135971/is-there-a-tool-to-discover-if-the-same-class-exists-in-multiple-jars-in-the-clas/4523559#4523559 should do the trick.

Comment: This worked. I don't think Tattletale handles jar files very well. If it does, I didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

[Classpath Helper](http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/) is an Eclipse plug-in that helps a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

I think it wouldn't be too hard to write a tool for your self.

You can get the classpath entries with System.getProperty("java.class.path");

And then walk through the jars, zips, or directories listed there and collect all the information about the classes and findout those that might cause trouble.

This task would take 1 or 2 days at most. Then you can load this class directly in your application and generate a report.

Probably java.class.path property wont's show all the classes if you run in some infrastructure with complex custom class loading ( for instance I once saw an app that load the classes from the LDAP )  but it would certainly work for most of the cases.

Heres a tool you might find useful, I've never use it my self, but give it a try and let us know the result.

http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jpathreport/features.html

If you are going to create your own tool, here is the code I use for the same shell script   posted before, but that I use on my Windows machine. It runs faster when there are tons of jar files.

You can use it and modify it  so instead of recursively walk a directory, read the class path and compare the .class time attribute.

There is a Command class you can subclass if needed, I was thinking in the -execute option of "find"

This my own code, so it was not intended to be "production ready", just to do the work.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;


public class ListZipContent{
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException {
        System.out.println( "start " + new java.util.Date() );
        String pattern = args.length == 1 ? args[0] : "OracleDriver.class";// Guess which class I was looking for :) 
        File file = new File(".");
        FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter(){
            public boolean accept( File file ){
                return file.isDirectory() || file.getName().endsWith( "jar" );
            }
        };
        Command command = new Command( pattern );
        executeRecursively( command, file, fileFilter );
        System.out.println( "finish  " + new java.util.Date() );
    }
    private static void executeRecursively( Command command, File dir , FileFilter filter ) throws IOException {
        if( !dir.isDirectory() ){
            System.out.println( "not a directory " + dir );
            return;
        }
        for( File file : dir.listFiles( filter ) ){
            if( file.isDirectory()){
                executeRecursively( command,file , filter );
            }else{
                command.executeOn( file );
            }
        }
    }
}
class Command {

    private String pattern;
    public Command( String pattern ){
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public void executeOn( File file ) throws IOException {
        if( pattern == null ) { 
            System.out.println( "Pattern is null ");
            return;
        }

        String fileName = file.getName();
        boolean jarNameAlreadyPrinted = false;

        ZipInputStream zis = null;
        try{
            zis = new ZipInputStream( new FileInputStream( file ) );

            ZipEntry ze;
            while(( ze = zis.getNextEntry() ) != null ) {
                if( ze.getName().endsWith( pattern )){
                    if( !jarNameAlreadyPrinted ){
                        System.out.println("Contents of: " + file.getCanonicalPath()  );
                        jarNameAlreadyPrinted = true;
                    }
                    System.out.println( "    " + ze.getName() );
                }
                zis.closeEntry();
            }
        }finally{
            if( zis != null ) try {
                zis.close();
            }catch( Throwable t ){}
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: why would you spend 1 or 2 days when there are likely tools that'll do it for you? If you aren't working on your project direcetly for 1 or 2 days it better be a hobby or you are doing something wrong.

Comment: The link http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jpathreport/features.html is dead. Could you please update it?

Comment: JPathReport seems to be long dead now, but I found this mirror: https://web.archive.org/web/20120209215148/http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jpathreport/features.html along with this download page: https://web.archive.org/web/20080626003101/http://www.jgoodies.com:80/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 3):

If you dislike downloading and installing stuff you can use this one line command to find jar conflicts with standard gnu tools. It is rudimentary but you can expand it as you will.

```
ls *.jar | xargs -n1 -iFILE unzip -l FILE | grep class | sed "s,.* ,," | tr "/" "." | sort | uniq -d | xargs -n1 -iCLASS grep -l CLASS *.jar | sort -u
```

(it is a bit slow to run if you have a lot of jars)

Explanation: 
It lists all the files in all the jars, greps for class files, finds dupes, then greps the original jars to see where they appeared. It could be made more efficient with a more complicated script.

Answer (score 0):

[jarclassfinder](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jarclassfinder) is another eclipse plugin option

Comment: The product's description says that it's a "plug-in utility for finding Java Archive (JAR) files containing a given class for the Java build path of a project." This is the opposite of what I need. I need to know if the same class is in two jars, NOT which jar a given class is in.

Comment: It will detect that a given class is in multiple jars, but it won't find all cases of classes in multiple jars.