# How to detect duplicate JARs in the classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

Does anyone have code to detect duplicate JARs in the classpath?

Background: When there are two versions of the same JAR in the classpath, really strange things can happen. This can even happen when using tools like Maven: Change a dependency and build the WAR without cleaning first. Since `target/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` wasn't cleaned, the dependency will be in there twice.

Is there a safety-net for this?

Comment: Verify if this can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555928/remove-duplicate-jars-in-a-directroy/20611435#20611435

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicated classes in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536482/find-duplicated-classes-in-classpath)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[JBoss Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) might help you with this.

It's a free tool which scans the JAR files used by your project and gives you a report about them.

Amongst its feature are:

- Spot if a class is located in multiple JAR files
- Spot if the same JAR file is located in multiple locations
- Find similar JAR files that have different version numbers

Answer (score 6):

There is a Maven plugin to do just that: [maven-duplicate-finder-plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin)

**[EDIT]** If you want to do it in unit tests yourself, use

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResources( "com/pany/package/Java.class" )
```

If this returns more than one `URL`, you have duplicates on the classpath.

The drawback is that this only works for cases where you had conflicts in the past. On the positive side, it's just a few lines of code (or one line when you write a helper method) and it works on your build server.

Answer (score 2):

`System.getProperty("java.class.path")`, split it, sort it, look at it with the human eye 
:-).

It will not include the classpath derived from manifests inside other jars thou :-(.

Or use http://www.jboss.org/tattletale as one of the posters suggested.

Comment: This assumes that your dupes have the same name. Often the problem is duplicate classes in jars with different names. You'd need more than one pair of eyeballs there.

Comment: Usually, the names will be different only in a version somewhere (usually a suffix).  Programmatically you could detect and highlight common prefixes.

Comment: You only need some sort of a warning sign in certain cases. What I proposed can be coded in 2 minutes and run as some sort of smoke test to catch "normal/easy" duplicates at the application startup. If you want extensive analysis use a tool like the tattletale proposed :-).

Answer (score 1):

I think the *simplest* way is to simply trash the target directory first. Hopefully copying all the .jar files in isn't going to be time-consuming.

Otherwise you're going to have to somehow compare sizable files (whether directly, via computed checksum or similar). Which doesn't sound very nice at all.

Answer (score -2):

You can write a simple script to compare the md5 sum of every jar file to every other jar file and deleting duplicates along the way.

Comment: two versions means by definition that the md5 sum will not match :-)

Comment: ah sorry, missed the different version part of your question