# Find duplicate properties file from class path of a deployed application in JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss

My Application (ear) has 2 jar and 2 war files. I want to find out if a properties file (xyz.xml) appear twice or more in the class path. I tried with`URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("xyz.xml");` . But this process return only the 1st appearance of the properties file. It's stop looking further once it gets the file in any jar/war. But , I do need all the occurrences of this properties file in my application. I am new in Java EE world, spend plenty of time to figure this out.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicated classes in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536482/find-duplicated-classes-in-classpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Enumeration<URL> urls = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("xyz.xml");
```

This finds all the resources with the given name.

See more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources%28java.lang.String%29